# Parpadeo al cambiar con js un elemento a posición fixed

Tags: jquery, scroll

resulta que tengo un menú que quiero, según va llegando el scroll que se mantenga fijo en la pantalla.

Lo hace bien, pero al llegar empieza a parpadear, se quita y se pone como loco.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var sticky2   = $(".conte-botk")[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + $(window)['scrollTop']();  


    var sticky = $(".conte-botk");

    var scrolle = $(window).scrollTop();



  if (scrolle > sticky2) {

        sticky.addClass('fixed');

  }else{

        sticky.removeClass('fixed');

    } 


});
```

He probado a sacar fuera la variable sticky2 de la función scroll y el problema se soluciona, pero deja de ser exacto al cambiar el tamaño de la ventana del navegador. ¿Alguien podría darme una solución?

Comment: Muchas gracias @JuanGlezz, voy a hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de dar con la solución, no sé si es muy elegante, pero funciona. He sacado la variable sticky2 fuera de la función scroll, pero cuando dicha variable es menor que la variable scrolle, lo que hago es pasar el valor de la variable sticky2 a entero, quedando así guardado siempre el mismo valor. En el caso contrario, la variable vuelve a contener el valor que tenía al comienzo.

```
    var sticky2   = $(".conte-botk")[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + $(window)['scrollTop']();  

  $(window).scroll(function(){

        var sticky = $(".conte-botk");

        var scrolle = $(window).scrollTop();



      if (scrolle > sticky2) {

            sticky.addClass('fixed');

         sticky2=parseIn(sticky2);


      }else{

            sticky.removeClass('fixed');
           sticky2   = $(".conte-botk")[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + $(window)['scrollTop']();  


        } 


    });
```

Ha dejado de parpadear y aún cambiando la anchura de la ventana del navegador sigue siendo exacto el sitio donde el div cambia a posición fixed.